# Error de aplicacion al ejecutar una linea. Hace referencia a memoria en 0x00000000. La memoria no se pudo read

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria, memoria

aquí esta mi programa el cual me dispara ese error

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void almacenarNumeros(int *, int);
void buscar(int *, int);

int *arreglo, nElementos;
bool band = false;

int main(){
    cout<<"Digita la cantidad de numeros del arreglo: "<<endl; 
    cin>>nElementos;
    
    almacenarNumeros(arreglo, nElementos);
    
    buscar(arreglo, nElementos);
    
    if(band == true){
        cout<<"Ese elemento pertenece al arreglo!"<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"No se encontro ese elemento"<<endl;
    }
    
    delete[] arreglo;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void almacenarNumeros(int *arreglo, int nElem){
    arreglo = new int[nElem];
    
    for(int i=0; i<nElem; i++){
        cout<<"\nIngresa el elemento de la posicion ["<<i<<"]: "<<endl;
        cin>>*(arreglo+i);
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<nElem; i++){
        cout<<*(arreglo+i)<<" ";
    }
}

void buscar(int *arreglo, int nElem){
    int dato;
    cout<<"\nDigita el numero a buscar: "<<endl; cin>>dato;
    int i=0;
    while((band==false) && (i<nElem)){
        if(dato == *(arreglo+i)){
            band = true;
        }
        i++;
    }

}
```

Compila de forma normal pero sospecho que el error sucede en la linea del condicional if de la función buscar(), y ahí el programa crashea, porque si la elimino, "funciona normalmente" aunque no hace lo que requiero que es buscar el elemento de mi arreglo, no se que hacer, he intentado cambiar la sintaxis y expresiones y nada. Espero que me ayuden, gracias de antemano.

Comment: A `almacenarNumeros` le pasas una copia de`arreglo`, no `arreglo` en si. Tienes que usar una referencia a el puntero, o un puntero a un puntero.

Answer (score 0):

Te está pasando lo siguiente:

1. La variable global `arreglo` al ser global se inicializa a cero (es una característica de C++, está así especificado en el estándar).
2. Cuando llamas  `almacenarNumeros` pasándole `arreglo` pasas una copia, los cambios hechos a esa copia no salen de la función, el `arreglo` global sigue estando a valor cero.
3. Cuando llamas a `buscar` vuelves a pasar una copia de `arreglo` el cuál es cero, cuando intentas leer te dice que (obviamente) no puede leer en cero.

---

Ese es el fallo obvio de tu código, el cuál surge de un claro fallo de diseño: ¿Para qué quieres variables globales si después las vas a pasar por parámetro? Decídete: o usas variables globales o usas parámetros.

En mi opinión, no deben usarse variables globales para este caso:

```
#include <iostream>

void almacenarNumeros(int *&arreglo, int nElem) // Ya no es puntero, es referencia a puntero
{
    arreglo = new int[nElem];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nElem; ++i) {
        std::cout<<"\nIngresa el elemento de la posicion ["<<i<<"]: \n";
        std::cin >> arreglo[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nElem; ++i) {
        std::cout << arreglo[i] <<" ";
    }
}

bool buscar(const int *const arreglo, int nElem) // Constante porque solo queremos leer
{
    int dato;
    std::cout << "\nDigita el numero a buscar: \n";
    std::cin >> dato;

    for (int i = 0; i < nElem; ++i)
    {
        if (dato == arreglo[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "Digita la cantidad de numeros del arreglo: \n"; 
    int nElementos;
    std::cin >> nElementos;

    int *arreglo;
    almacenarNumeros(arreglo, nElementos);
    if (buscar(arreglo, nElementos)) {
        std::cout << "Ese elemento pertenece al arreglo!\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "No se encontro ese elemento\n";
    }
    
    delete[] arreglo;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Por mencionar otra posibilidad, la función `almacenarNumeros` podría simplemente devolver el puntero y se utilizaría así: `arreglo = almacenarNumeros(nElementos);`

Comment: La mejor opción en mi opinión, sería devolver un contenedor.